# If there difference between `\A` vs `^` (caret) in regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Python's [`re` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) says:

> `^`: (Caret.) Matches the start of the string, and in MULTILINE mode also matches immediately after each newline.
>
> `\A`: Matches only at the start of the string.

Is there any difference when using them?

Comment: You have just stated their difference. `\A` is unambiguous string start anchor. `^` can change its behavior depending on the modifier. What kind of answer do you want to get?

Comment: Ok, do you mean you'd like to know when it is OK to use them? It is still related to that difference you already pointed out. When you want to match either start of a string OR a line, you use `^`, when you only need to match the start of a string, use `\A`.

Comment: `\A` is interesting in particular when you build a pattern with multiline mode and you have to distinguish between the start of the line and the start of the string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both of these match:

```
re.search('^abc', 'abc')
re.search('\Aabc', 'abc')
```

This also matches:

```
re.search('^abc', 'firstline\nabc', re.M)
```

This does not:

```
re.search('\Aabc', 'firstline\nabc', re.M)
```

Comment: Just verified that `re.search('^abc', 'firstline\nabc')` doesn't match as expected. Thanks for your examples!

Answer (score 3):

`\A` is unambiguous string start anchor. `^` can change its behavior depending on whether the `re.M` modifier is used or not.

*When to use `\A` and when to use `^`?*

When you want to match either start of a string *OR* a line, you use `^`, when you only need to match the start of a string *regardless of any modifiers*, use `\A`. You may re-use one and the same string pattern but compile it with different flags.

This also means that if you are using `re.M` flag, and you want to match the string start and then line start positions, you will mix the `\A` and `^` inside that pattern.